# D3 onclick not using local variables

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to set this map value based on the i and j values. I thought if I passed them in they would use the local values, but I'm getting 0 and undefined for i and j when I click any of them.
But the Ids are the correct values.
The Arrays are populated.

```
let j = 1
    for (const string of yStart) {
        let i = 0;
        for (let fret of fretPositionsArray) {
            d3.select("#fretboard")
                .append('rect')
                .on("click", function (i,j) {
                    let strfrt = { str: j, frt: i}
                    music.set(Math.random(), strfrt);

                    for (let k of music.keys()) {
                       // console.log(k)
                    }
                    for (let v of music.values()) {
                        console.log(v)
                    }
                    localStorage.setItem("testMusic", JSON.stringify(Array.from(music.entries())));

                })
                .on("mouseover", function () {
                    d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'green')
                })
                .on('mouseout', function () {
                    d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'orange')
                })
                .attr("id", "S" + j + "F" + (i + 1))
                .attr('x', fret)
                .attr('y', string)
                .attr('width', fretWidthArray[i])
                .attr('height', 30)
                //.attr('stroke', 'green')
                .attr('stroke-linecap', 'butt')
                .attr('stroke-width', '1')
                .attr('fill', '#FFFAEF')
                .attr('fill-opacity', .1)
            i++
        }
        j++
    }
```

Comment: I recommend , create a function with the code of the second for, and send the two parameter s (i,j), and invoke the function inside the for , so the variables scope can change.

Answer (score 0):

D3 dictates the parameters of your "click" callback.  Remove them completely from your anonymous function:

```
.on("click", function () {
```

From the Docs on `d3.selection.on`

> When a specified event is dispatched on a selected element, the
> specified listener will be evaluated for the element, being passed the
> current event (event) and the current datum (d), with this as the
> current DOM element (event.currentTarget).

So in the scope of your callback, `i` was now the event and `j` was now the datum